# MVC 5 Referencing ApplicationUser outside of the default context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting to create a foreign key to an application user. The model that I am putting this references in is not part of the default context. This means all of my user data is in another database. This seems to be causing me some issues.

My model looks like this

```
public class ThreadModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ThreadId { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual PostModel LatestPost { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SubThreadModel> SubThreads { get; set; }
}

public class SubThreadModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SubThreadId { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsPinned { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual PostModel LatestPost { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class PostModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubThreadModel Topic { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeEdited { get; set; }
    public bool IsRemoved { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PostLikeModel> Likes { get; set; }
}
```

The errors that I am getting are :

```
MyPage.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the    key for this EntityType.
MyPage.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

Comment: Maybe you could try posting the IdentityUserLogin and IdentityUserRole classes for clarification? I'm confused on how they relate to classes you did post.

Comment: Me too, I am only using the one provided by the framework. I'm assuming they are brought into this because ApplicationUser inherits Identity and I'm guessing Identity is made up of those other objects.